# KnowRob for Hydro

Tags: ros-hydro, knowrob

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are there any plans to catkinize the KnowRob packages and release them for Hydro?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/120826/knowrob-for-hydro/) by [ZeynSaigol](https://answers.ros.org/users/11101/zeynsaigol/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-01-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just to note Moritz has now produced a Catkinized version - see http://www.knowrob.org/blog/catkinized_version_of_knowrob_available and http://www.knowrob.org/installation/catkin

---

Originally posted by [zsaigol](https://answers.ros.org/users/6094/zsaigol/) with karma: 225 on 2015-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0